# Настройка авторизации iis для clickonce

Tags: авторизация, iis, clickonce

Я начинающий DevOps, недавно познакомился с технологии clickonce.
В общем руководство приняло решение обновлять WPF приложения на удаленных терминалах с помощью этой технологии. Делаю публикацию на ftp-сервер, оттуда iis выводит в директорию сайта файлы приложения. Теперь вопрос, как закрыть эту директорию от всего интернета и предоставить скачивание только определенным хостам? Пробовал настроить авторизацию на iis по сертификату, но ничего не получилось. Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным, прошу помощи. Может кто может подсказать другие методы аутентификации?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что ваш вопрос не относится ни к C#, ни к WPF, ни к ClickOnce?

Comment: Поправил метки для соответствия вопросу. Надо еще заголовок поправить...